# get value from Previous row in power bi measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, measure

Please help me....!!!

I have a data set containing budget data and which months those budgeted values will be received. I have another column called 'Exposure' and I'm in trouble with how to get the previous value record and calculate the exposure column.I want to get this done in Power bi measure.
Here is the dataset and measure in an Excel file

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19jgEY3BpOPOnlJEAiV4O4YHRnVU2gnyF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113771256766777912189&rtpof=true&sd=true

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cGls.png)

I want to get this done in Power bi.

Comment: Please explain how the math is supposed to work. Previous value for what?

Comment: The previous value of last month.

Comment: Oh, you can use CALCULATE for that.
CALCULATE(<measure>, PREVIOUSMONTH('DimDate'[DateKey]))

Comment: yes, I can take it using the previous month but I do this for the entire year.so I have summed up the previous month's Exposure to the current month. I was confused in that part.